# Example of Darmois Skitovitch theorem

Tags: independence

In looking at something, I stumbled across the awesome Darmois-Skitovitch theorem:

Define two random variables $y_1$ and $y_2$ as linear combinations of independent random variables $s_i$ $(i=1, · · · , q)$:

$$y_1=\sum_{i=1}^q\alpha_i s_i$$
$$y_2=\sum_{i=1}^q\beta_i s_i$$

Then, if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are independent, all variables $s_j$ for which $a_jb_j \neq 0$ are Gaussian.

Although not explicit in the theorem, this seems to indicate that if some of the $s_j$ are Gaussian, you can have some of those $a_jb_j \neq 0$ and have $y_1$ and $y_2$ be independent. I tried to create some simple examples of this, but have not been successful. It is easy to do if the $s_j$ are not independent, but that's not what I'm looking for. Anyone have a good example (or way of looking at it)?

Comment: @Xi'an yes, I'm looking for an example where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are independent but where they are each linear combinations of random variables with some coefficients for both being non-zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X_1, X_2$ be iid $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Then $Y_1 = X_1 + X_2$ and $Y_2 = X_1 - X_2$ [are independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1091171/646321).

This is also an example of the stricter Kac-Bernstein theorem.

Example: Throw two darts at a 1D target. Each throw is independent. If the distance between the two darts and the summed distance of the two darts from the center are independent then the distance of each dart from the center is a Gaussian variable.

Comment: This is literally just repeating the theorem; I think he wants examples of $X_1$ and $X_2$ that can produce the phenomenon

Comment: Added concrete example

Comment: very nice example

Comment: Thanks! Can I look at it this way? If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both, for example $N(0, 1)$ then $Y_1 = X_1 + X_2$ and $Y_2 = X_1 - X_2$ are independent, right? If that's right, I'll need to work out some examples why that works when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are Gaussian, but not when they are other distributions.

Comment: @roundsquare yes, see Kac-Bernstein theorem and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091111/independence-of-sum-and-difference-for-random-vectors

Comment: @PierreGourseaud thank you very much! This is a great example - once I worked it out (not that hard as it turns out), it also helped me to see why the normal distribution is "special" as relates to the Darmois-Skitovitch theorem.

Answer (score 0):

It works when they are Gaussian because they have zero covariance, and zero covariance implies independence for Gaussian distributions. It is not independence for non-Gaussian distributions. For example, if the variables are uniform.